# How to search for a string pattern inside html, coding in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, strstr

I need to search for titles(string) inside a html file.
For this, i did the strstr to get the tag "li" which contains the tag "title= \", which contains the string that i want.

For example: using this array below, i need to get the name of the book, inside title. However, i need all the titles inside the html body, which has hundreds.

```
<li><i><a href="/wiki/Animal_Farm" title="Animal Farm">A Revolução dos Bichos</a></i> (<a href="/wiki/1945" title="1945">1945</a>), de <a href="/wiki/George_Orwell" title="George Orwell">George Orwell</a>.</li>
```

I was trying to run a "for" using strlen to get its loop condition (line length). Inside this for, i used strstr to get the title=" to finally copy the string until the end of the quotation marks.

something like this:

```
for (i=0, i<len, i++){
    if(strstr(array[i] == " title=\""){
        do{
    temp[i] = array[i];
          }while((strcmp(array[i], "\""));
    }
}
```

That's the point i struggled with. How to get strings, inside strings, using patterns(conditions)?
Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!
Regards.

Comment: What you really need is a frontend from compiler construction. But I guess this kind of work is over your skill atm. Can't you use an existing HTML parser library?

Comment: strstr takes it's first arg as a string pointer.  It also returns a string pointer.  So simply load the entire file into a char array, look for title=" set the start of that to "foundtitle" then do a strstr for " using "foundtitle" as the start string pointer.  Use pointer arithmetic to get the size of the title that's found and either strdup it into an array of char * or store the start point and length.  Then repeat, using the end of the found title as the start point

Comment: you are absolutely right @bash0r. it is too sophisticated for me, as i could see. but i will learn more about it, definitely. thank you!

Comment: i got your point. i will try counting the length of the string (i mean, the substring) and see if it works. that's make sense. thank you @Vorsprung.

Comment: @renan_c If you need help with basics of compiler construction, just write me an e-mail. I had problems with this kind of things myself once and I'd be happy to share my knowledge and experience. Compiler construction is far too less appreciated by most developers and they don't understand their tools due to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML parsing "the right way" is way more complicated than checking for one string at a time. My code below does more things *not* right than the other way around -- but part of this is due to a lack of information.

Is your HTML well-formed? Can the `title` attribute contain the strings `li` or `title`, or stray `<` or `>` characters? Do you need to take into account that spaces may occur inside tags, such as `< li >`? Are all attributes written with double quotes `"`, or can there be single quotes `'` as well?

My code shows the *general* idea of HTML parsing: hop from one `<` to the next and inspect the HTML command that follows it. But as you can see, it's ugly as hell and, while it "does the job", it's nigh on unmaintanable.

For a quick rush job within well defined parameters, it'll probably do; for all others, look for a general HTML parsing library, which will shield you from the caveats mentioned above and provide a user-friendly interface to elements and attributes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "<li><i><a href=\"/wiki/Animal_Farm\" title=\"Animal Farm\">A Revolução dos Bichos</a></i> (<a href=\"/wiki/1945\" title=\"1945\">1945</a>), de <a href=\"/wiki/George_Orwell\" title=\"George Orwell\">George Orwell</a>.</li>"
                "<li><i><a href=\"/wiki/Animal_Farm_II\" title=\"Animal Farm II: Return of the Hog\">A Revolução dos Bichos</a></i> (<a href=\"/wiki/1945\" title=\"1945\">1945</a>), de <a href=\"/wiki/George_Orwell\" title=\"George Orwell\">George Orwell</a>.</li>";
    char *html_walker;
    html_walker = str;
    do
    {
        html_walker = strstr(html_walker, "<");
        if (!html_walker)
            break;
        /* Is this "LI"? */
        if (!strncasecmp(html_walker+1, "LI", 2) &&
            !isalnum(html_walker[3]))
        {
            /* Yes. Scan following HTML entries for 'title' until we find an "</LI>" */
            do
            {
                /* an "</LI>" code. Bye. */
                if (*html_walker == '<')
                {
                    html_walker++;
                    if (!strncasecmp(html_walker+1, "/LI", 3) &&
                        !isalnum(html_walker[4]))
                    {
                        while (*html_walker && *html_walker != '>')
                            html_walker++;
                        if (*html_walker == '>')
                            html_walker++;
                        break;
                    }
                    /* Not an "</LI>" code. Look for 'title' */
                    while (*html_walker && *html_walker != '>')
                    {
                        if (isspace (*html_walker) &&
                            !strncasecmp(html_walker+1, "TITLE=\"", 7))
                        {
                            html_walker += 8;
                            printf ("title [");
                            while (*html_walker && *html_walker != '"')
                            {
                                printf ("%c", *html_walker);
                                html_walker++;
                            }
                            printf ("]\n"); fflush (stdout);
                            /* We found a title, so skip to next </LI> */
                            do
                            {
                                html_walker = strstr(html_walker, "<");
                                if (!html_walker)
                                    break;
                                /* Is this "/LI"? */
                                if (!strncasecmp(html_walker+1, "/LI", 3) &&
                                    !isalnum(html_walker[4]))
                                    break;
                                html_walker++;
                            } while (html_walker && *html_walker);
                            break;
                        }
                        html_walker++;
                    }
                    if (*html_walker == '>')
                        html_walker++;
                } else
                {
                    html_walker++;
                }
            } while (*html_walker);
        } else
        {
            /* Skip forward to next '<' */
            html_walker++;
        }
    } while (html_walker && *html_walker);
    return 0;
}
```